# How to keep previous submitted value from user, add it to next one, and so on. Django 2.1

Tags: django

i am new to Django and Python. I wanna achieve something and i struggle with that for over a week.

I have a simple form with one field where user can input some number, after he submit it, i return to him that same number on same page. If he submit again i wanna add that number with previous one. How can i do that?

For example:

**User submit 1**

*I return 1*

**User submit 3**

*i return 4*

i wanna keep previous submitted number and add it to next one.

Comment: By storing it in a *database*.

Comment: But it will never start from 0 again. :(

Comment: why not? You can remove things from a database as well...

Comment: Oh so i can put some kind of "restart" feature inside template that will update value in database to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many solutions to this. 
You can use the Sessions if your **users** aren't supposed to be logged in, or you can even use the database.